# Anything wrong with my python Monty hall simulation?

Tags: python, statistics

Did I go wrong somewhere? I keep getting 50% wins even after switching.

```
import random

def monty_hall():

    #-----setup ----#

    prizes = ["Car" , "Goat" , "Goat"]
    random.shuffle(prizes)

    #----person chooses at random----#

    choose_index = random.randint(0,2)

    ##-------host reveals a goat------#

    while True:
        goat_gate = random.randint(0, 2)
        if prizes[goat_gate] == "Goat":
            break

    ##------person switches -------##

    while True:
        switch_choice = random.randint(0, 2)
        if (switch_choice!= choose_index) & (switch_choice!= goat_gate):
            break

    ## -- check if won---#

    if prizes[switch_choice] == "Car":
        return True

win = 0
games = 100000

for times in range(games):
    if monty_hall() == True:
        win += 1

print(win/games)
```

Comment: Am I the only one to read the title as "Monty Python hall simulation?"

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `&`, you should be using `and`, because `&` is bitwise and, not boolean and.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you didn't include the fact that the host will not reveal what's behind the chosen door.

```
while True :
    goat_gate = random.randint(0, 2)
    if prizes[goat_gate] == "Goat" :
        break
```

should be

```
while True :
    goat_gate = random.randint(0, 2)
    if prizes[goat_gate] == "Goat" and goat_gate != choose_index:
        break
```

Comment: To explain why you get 1/2: 1/3 of the time you pick the prize on the first shot, and so will always lose on switching.  2/3 of the time, you pick a goat.  As currently written, 1/2 the time your code will pick that same goat such that when you switch, 1/2 the time you'll pick the other goat.  1/3 + 2/3 * 1/4 = 1/3 + 1/6 = 1/2.